# How to call rule in graphDB?

Tags: graphdb

I want to create an inference in my project, that the goal is to link when the rule is good the Subject V (Valeur) and the Object TM Type_Mesure.
So I have done this rule in protege ontology editor (in SWRL):

```
modele:Modelisé_Avec(?MQ,?TM) ^ 
modele:Antecedent(?MS, ?MQ) ^
profil:A_Pour_Modèle_Système(?S, ?MS) ^
profil:A_Pour_Comportement(?MS, ?GC) ^ 
profil:A_Pour_Membre(?GC, ?C) ^ 
capt:A_Pour_Echantillon(?C, ?E) ^ 
capt:A_Pour_Valeur(?E,?V) ^ 
-> capt:Classifie_Metier(?V, ?TM)
```

I use tree ontologies in this case : Profil_V2,Modele_V2 and Capteur_V2

But graphDB don't accept this type of rule. So, i want to turn it to language who is accepted in grphDB.

I have already do this code :

```
PREFIX sys: <www.ontotext.com/owlim/system#>
PREFIX rdf: <www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX modele: <srv-rd-vm/ontology/Modele_V2#>
PREFIX profil: <srv-rd-vm/ontology/Profil_V2#>
PREFIX capt: <srv-rd-vm/ontology/Capteur_V2#>
INSERT DATA {
<_:profil_classification_Metier> sys:addRuleset
        '''Prefices { 
                    profil: <srv-rd-vm/ontology/Profil_V2#>
            modele: <srv-rd-vm/ontology/Modele_V2#>
            capt: <srv-rd-vm/ontology/Capteur_V2#>
            rdf: <www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
           }
           Axioms {}
           Rules
           {
            Id: profil_classification_Metier
                MQ <rdf:Type> <modele:MODELE_QUALIFICATION>
                MQ <modele:Modelisé_Avec> TM
                MS <modele:Antecedent> MQ
                S <profil:A_Pour_Modèle_Système> MS 
                MS <profil:A_Pour_Comportement> GC 
                GC <profil:A_Pour_Membre> C 
                C <capt:A_Pour_Echantillon> E 
                E <capt:A_Pour_Valeur> V 
                -------------------------------
                V <capt:Classifie_Metier> TM
           }'''
}
```

But I don't know how to call it when I create a new data.
For the moment I call the rule like that :

```
PREFIX capt: <http://srv-rd-vm/ontology/Capteur_V2#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX profil: <http://srv-rd-vm/ontology/Profil_V2#>
INSERT {
    [] <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/system#Test> [] .
    capt:test rdf:type capt:VALEUR .
 capt:test capt:Nom 'test'^^xsd:string .
 capt:test capt:Valeur '60.5042'^^xsd:float . 
 capt:echantillon capt:A_Pour_Valeur capt:test .
    
 capt:echantillon rdf:type capt:ECHANTILLON .
 capt:echantillon capt:Nom 'echantillon'^^xsd:string .
 capt:echantillon capt:Date '1695717396'^^xsd:dateTime .
 profil:comportement capt:A_Pour_Echantillon capt:echantillon.
    
 profil:comportement rdf:type profil:COMPORTEMENT .
 profil:comportement profil:Nom 'comportement'^^xsd:string .
 profil:9e7b483e_cec8_4ce7_8ae2_6e693859a043 profil:A_Pour_Membre  profil:comportement .
    
} 

WHERE {  };
```

When I use it like that the rule create a predicat with the same name as her and blank node.

[query to show the result of rule called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkD0g.png)

But when I set like default rule she works.

Do you known how to call it ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: 1. SHACL is a validation language, you can't use it to create new data. It only validates existing data.
2. What you have above isn't valid SHACL. See https://www.w3.org/wiki/SHACL/Examples for what SHACL normally looks like. Also read the SHACL docs as to how to properly write it
3. GraphDB works with RIF rule files for inferencing. See https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/reasoning.html for more information

Comment: For the record, SHACL has a companion spec called the Advanced Features that include inferencing rules: https://w3c.github.io/shacl/shacl-af/

One way of writing such rules is through SPARQL queries, and the rule in question here looks like it could be represented using SPARQL, at least in principle. So even without SHACL as a wrapper, it should be possible to write a script that runs SPARQL INSERT queries iteratively against a SPARQL endpoint, including GraphDB.

Comment: Hey, I have update my question !

Answer (score 1):

- You don't "call" a rule. You set up a ruleset, and then it's used for newly incoming data
- It's simplest to specify the ruleset when you make your repo. Why do you need to add it dynamically?
- As https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.3/rules-optimisations.html says, start from the **minimal** builtin ruleset then add your own rules. For each rule, know why you need it
- To add a ruleset dynamically, I think you also need to activate it (https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.3/reasoning.html#set-a-default-ruleset), and need to reinfer for it take effect on old data (https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.3/reasoning.html#reinferring)